Installing Oracle 21c DB on Ubuntu
I'm going crazy trying to create my DB on this OS (24.04LTS), I read from this post the KK Patel answe due to the same error on top
How to install SqlPlus?
Well, It's solved, but then when I try to execute sqlplus system/admin@//dbhost:1521/SID It gives me this error:
Script detail
I checked libaio versions and installed them yet, both of them found in the apt search.
enter image description here
libaio versions
Please help :) my chest hurts a bit
